# No module found error for a downloaded package (sksparse.cholmod) and how to download a package from the internet to conda

Tags: python, installation, package, conda, environment

I need to use the **sksparse.chomod** package however my pycharm does not let me install it as it can't seem to find it.
I found the sksparse package on github and downloaded it but I do not know how to add a package downloaded from the internet into a conda environment. So, my first question would be can you download a package from github and add it to your conda environment, and how do you do this?

As I did not know how to do the above I instead saved the package within my project and thought I could simply import sksparse.cholmod. However, the line in my code that says *import sksparse.cholmod as sks* has no errors with it, so I assumed that meant this was ok, but when I try to run my file I get this error:

```
    import sksparse.cholmod as sks
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sksparse.cholmod'
```

If I have downloaded the package into my project why can't it be found, yet there are no errors when importing?

The cholmod file is a pyx file which I've been told should not be a problem.

Please could anyone help, I am reasonably new to python and I am looking for a straight forward solution that won't be time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with windows, I was able to fix this using the instructions on this link
https://github.com/EmJay276/scikit-sparse

We must follow these steps precisely:

(This was tested with a Anaconda 3 installation and Python 3.7)

Install these requirements in order:

'''
conda install -c conda-forge numpy - tested with v1.19.1
conda install -c anaconda scipy - tested with v1.5.0
conda install -c conda-forge cython - tested with v0.29.21
conda install -c conda-forge suitesparse - tested with v5.4.0
'''

Download Microsoft Build Tools for C++ from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/visual-cpp-build-tools/ (tested with 2019, should work with 2015 or newer)

Install Visual Studio Build Tools

Choose Workloads
Check "C++ Buildtools"
Keep standard settings
Run  ''' pip install git+https://github.com/EmJay276/scikit-sparse '''

Test ''' from sksparse.cholmod import cholesky '''

Use all the versions stated for numpy etc, however with scipy I installed the latest version and it worked fine.